# php shorthand return statement

Tags: php, return, shorthand

So i was just recently looking for some examples of validating a unix timestamp.  One code chunk that kept reappearing was this:

```
function isValidTimeStamp($strTimestamp) {
    return ((string) (int) $strTimestamp === $strTimestamp) 
        && ($strTimestamp <= PHP_INT_MAX)
        && ($strTimestamp >= ~PHP_INT_MAX);
}
```

Now I have looked for shorthand return if statements which I think this might be but I am not having any luck. can anyone explain to me how this function is deciding what to return and how. Thanks

Comment: This is simply a good application of boolean algebra. The functions returns true if all 3 statements are true. This isn't the application of the short hand if statement, a.k.a ternary operator.

Comment: I understand the comparisons between $variables and Constants, but what are `(string)` and `(int)` for?

Comment: Thats simply an example of casting. (string) ensures that the value being used is actually a string, and (int) makes sure the value is an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of boolean operations (like `&&`, `||` or `==`) is a boolean, just as the result of numeric operations (like `+` and `*`) is a number. So exactly like `return 2 + 3` would yield 5, `return true && false` would return `false`. Now, operations can of course be nested. For example, `return (2 + 3) * (3 + 3)` is still a valid expression and yields 30. In the same manner, `return ($a === $b) && ($a => $c)` will yield a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

this is not unique to PHP (every language I know allows this). all that is happening here is that a condition (in this case a series of 3 conditions) is being evaluated and the result of that evaluation is being returned.

This function will either return `true` or `false` depending on all the conditions being met or not.